# How to set Grid images have uniform height and width

Tags: android

Friend's
    I have a task to parse thumbnail images and to set it on grid view,where url image content to be in different height and width(some images to be 60*60, or 110*80),how can i set images in grid have uniform height and width.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give your layout for the views created by the ListAdapter a fixed width and height sufficient for the largest dimensions, then position the ImageView centered inside e.g.:

```
<RelativeLayout 
     android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout01" 
     android:layout_width="100dip" 
     android:layout_height="80dip"    
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
     <ImageView 
          android:id="@+id/imageView" 
          android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:scaleType="centerInside">
    </ImageView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: thanks a lot.. for your answer,i really got the view i needed from your help.

Answer (score 0):

Give your layout for the views created by the ListAdapter a fixed width and height sufficient for the largest dimensions, then position the ImageView centered inside e.g.:

```
                <GridView
                android:id="@+id/gridView1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_margin="4dp"
                android:columnWidth="100dp"
                android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
                android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:numColumns="10"
                android:stretchMode="columnWidth"/>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer it's very helpful for me

Answer (score 0):

```
    <HorizontalScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/seatLegendLayout">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout_gridtableLayout"
            android:layout_width="900dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <GridView
                android:id="@+id/gridView1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_margin="4dp"
                android:columnWidth="100dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:numColumns="9"
                android:horizontalSpacing="1dp"
                android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawHorizontalTrack="true"
                android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true"
                android:scrollbars="horizontal"
                android:stretchMode="none"
                android:verticalSpacing="1dp">

            </GridView>


        </LinearLayout>
    </FrameLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

Comment: Nice answer very heluful for me