# How can i partition and use my grid in equal parts?

Tags: windows-phone-7, xaml, layout

I am using a Grid and in my page. The page should be equally partitioned like a ice cube tray.

The each grid column contains a image.

For partitioning into 3 equal parts i am using this code:

```
 <ListBox SelectionChanged="listBox1_SelectionChanged" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" Height="720" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="1,5,0,0" Name="listBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <toolkit:WrapPanel />
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="3" >
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                            <Border CornerRadius="6" BorderBrush="Gray" BorderThickness="2" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" x:Name="border1">

                                <toolkit:WrapPanel x:Name="wp">
                                        <Image Source="{Binding ImagePicture}"  Margin="0,10,0,0" Height="110" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                                        <TextBlock  Margin="0,0,0,5" TextAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding categoryname}" Foreground="Black" FontStyle="Normal" Height="Auto" Width="140" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
                                    </toolkit:WrapPanel>
                                </Border>

                            </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
```

Now when i use this, sometimes the images are small i face this problem i have shown.

This is what i Want:

[image: This is what i want]

This is my problem:

[image: This is my problem]

Can you please share the solution for this problem.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3565066/how-to-set-grid-images-have-uniform-height-and-width try this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This xaml will work-

```
   <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
```

Comment: I am using this grid definitions inside a DataTemplate. And also i have edited the code in my question.